# SRAM X01 Eagle (12speed) in 11speed transmission: it work?

Tags: gears, derailleur, shifter, derailleur-rear, sram

Well, I intend to use an SRAM X01 Eagle (12speed) rear derailleur in a 1x11 transmission (with a SRAM X01 "non-Eagle" 11speed trigger, cassette SunRace 11s 11-46, SRAM PC XX1 chain).
Will it work perfectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the SRAM 1x11 and 1x12 drivetrains use the SRAM [X-ACTUATION™](https://www.sram.com/sram/mountain/technologies/x_actuation) technology. This means they both have the same cable pull ratio. I have not tried this but the derailleurs should be interchangeable - keeping in mind the Eagle derailleur will be better suited for larger range cassettes.

Edit: Here is someone who is using an XX1 shifter with an Eagle derailleur: https://endless-sphere.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=88323

> Setup:
>   11-50T 11 cog Garbaruk cassette
>   X01 Eagle Rear Derailleur 12 gear
>   XX1 X-ACTUATION Trigger Shifter 11 gear
>
> The SRAM 12 speed X01 derailleur has the same cable pull ratio as the
>   SRAM 11 speed XX1 derailleur. This means you can interchange the X01
>   and XX1 derailleurs between the 11 and 12 gear drivetrains.
>
> My guess on this setup proved right and I get excellent shifting with
>   no backpedal chain drops.

Comment: I asked SRAM specifically about 11S and 12S cable pull. They replied: "The shifters between groups of different speeds do not have the same amount of cable pull." Given that the 12S cassette sprocket pitch is less than 11S, this would explain why the 12S derailleur works with the 11S shifter; it appears it's actually the 12S shifter that differs, X-ACTUATION marketing aside.

Answer (score 5):

To quote [Art's Cyclery](http://blog.artscyclery.com/mountain/gear-srams-12-speed-eagle-group-overview/):

"Eagle drivetrains are not backwards compatible in any way (the exception being SRAM’s direct mount cranksets, which will still require a new Eagle chainring)"

and [VitalMTB](http://www.vitalmtb.com/features/First-Look-First-Ride-SRAM-Eagle-1x12-Drivetrain-The-Front-Derailleur-Killer,1335):

"SRAM will only make the Eagle chainring in the direct-mount style at first, and we were told it's the only Eagle component compatible with their 1x11 drivetrains. No 11-speed products will work on Eagle."

Comment: Well, I tested. 
SRAM X01 11s shifters + SRAM X01 Eagle 12s rear derailleur + SRAM XG1150 10-42 cassete + KMC X11SL chain, and works perfectly. 
I have tested too: SRAM X01 Eagle 12s shifters + SRAM GX 11s rear derailleur + SRAM Eagle 10-50 cassete + SRAM PC-XX1 chain, and works great. Apparently, is only the shifter who defines the operation of the rear derailleur 11 or 12s. And physically the 11 and 12s rear derailleurs work well under both conditions.
Anyway, thank you guys.

Comment: You should add that as an answer then accept it.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because manufacturers don't encourage mixing and matching of various drivetrain components due to variuos reasons, and these might have nothing to do with actual "incompatibility".

Answer (score 1):

And 12 speed XTR and Eagle has that same 1.1 ratio and are compatibile. See

Comment: Same for 11 speed, I'm using 11 speed SLX derailleur with GX 11 speed grip shifters. So finally after about 30 years the two companies mtb parts are compatible (11-12sp), you can use gripshifts with shimano derailleurs etc.